# Quick Parameterization Help

Tags: parametric

I've been trying to paramaterize

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9,\ x^2-y^2=3$$

but haven't had any luck. I was thinking to let $x=\sqrt{3}\ \sec(t), y=\sqrt{3}\ \tan(t)$ to complete the identity on the right equation, but when going back to the left one and solving for $z$, I get a nonreal result.

Comment: This is the intersection of a sphere with a hyperbolic cylinder.  The intersection will be two disjoint "loops" on the sphere.  Perfectly good coordinates on a sphere are spherical coordinates ...

Comment: Are you trying to parametrize each equation on its own or their intersection?

Comment: I am not as familiar with spherical coordinates. The overall problem is to find the equation of an oscillating plane, but I would like them in terms of parameter t.

Comment: And I'm trying to do it on their intersection I assume (so that the x and y satisfy both equations)

Comment: The intersection "curve" has two disjoint pieces, so you can't parameterize the whole thing. The solutions already given will allow you to parameterize either one piece or the other, and that's probably all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sphere equation becomes

$$ z^2 \ = \ 9 \ - \ 3 \sec^2 t \ - \ 3 \tan^2 t   $$

$$ = \ 9 \ - \ 3 \ (\tan^2 t \ + \ 1 )  - \ 3 \tan^2 t \ = \ 6 \ - \ 6 \tan^2 t \ . $$

Doesn't seem like there's anything problematic there, since $ \ |z| \ \le \ 3 \ $ ; the upper bound on $ \ z^2 \ $ of 6 represents the greatest "altitude" from the $ \ xy-$ plane where the surfaces intersect.  There will be two square-roots, corresponding to locations on the two hemispheres about the $ \ xy-$ plane.  (I'm adding a picture of the surfaces.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have a problem that I'm working on for class, I just needed to paramaterize it first. I must have made a mistake somewhere else...

Comment: I'm not sure this does _that_ job (parameterizing the intersection curves) fully:  that's why I was wondering what the intention is... [response to a comment now gone]

Comment: No it doesn't do the job fully, but it gets me on track, I know where to go from here just fine. I didn't post the whole problem, just needed this as a jumping off point. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: Your answer is correct.